# Change column to row using awk inside of GRASS command

Tags: grass-gis, linux, bash

I have 2000+ raster files and counting their statistics.
For now I am exporting all to Excel, but to work on it, I need better segregation.

My output:

```
Name1
1  123
2  243
3  455
Name2
1  432
3  655
4  234
Name3
2  344
3  345...
```

I have 4 possibilities: 1, 2, 3 and 4, but not all rasters have all combinations. I would like to use awk to create output like that:

```
name   1    2    3    4
Name1  123  243  455    
Name2  432       655  234
Name3       344  345
```

So I was trying with this:

```
for red in {43..64}
do
for nir in {65..193}
do
r.stats -cnl 'gr_r'$red'_n'$nir | \
awk '$1 == 1 {print($2)}' ...
```

And how to create different rows?

Comment: This isn't a GIS or grass specific question and belongs on stackoverflow or unix.stackexchange.com - and by 'belongs' there I think you'll get better answers there, not that I see anything wrong with the answer from @Tomasz.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the names are not in the form of two numbers, you can pipe to this:

```
perl -wlne'BEGIN {$,="\t"; @a=qw(name 1 2 3 4)}
if (/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/) {$a[$1]=$2;}
else {print @a if @a; @a=(); $a[0]=$_} END{print @a if @a}'
```

Don't worry about the warnings, the output won't contain them when you redirect it to a file. They're about empty array items. You can silence them by removing the `w` option, ie. call Perl with

```
perl -lne
```

So the whole loop would be:

```
for f in gr_r{43..64}_n{65..193}; do
    r.stats -cnl "$f"
done | perl -wlne'BEGIN {$,="\t"; @a=qw(name 1 2 3 4)}
    if (/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/) {$a[$1]=$2;}
    else {print @a if @a; @a=(); $a[0]=$_} END{print @a if @a}'
```

As above, it's better to pipe the whole loop to a single Perl process rather than calling it for every `r.stats` instance. It would be better to also call `r.stats` just once if possible.

You can redirect the result to a file as usual, that is using the `>` redirection. So here's the whole bunch:

```
for f in gr_r{43..64}_n{65..193}; do
    r.stats -cnl "$f"
done | >output.file perl -wlne'BEGIN {$,="\t"; @a=qw(name 1 2 3 4)}
    if (/^(\d+)\s+(\d+)$/) {$a[$1]=$2;}
    else {print @a if @a; @a=(); $a[0]=$_} END{print @a if @a}'
```